# How to develop java application on remote ubuntu server?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I want to check my app I need to compile it upload it to my server and run it.
It takes lot of time. and I can't debug.

Is there some more effective way to do it? Or even debug on my remote server?

I prefer to use eclipse but any compiler that do the job is good.
And I can't debug the app on my local pc because it use some linux based packages
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to write a script (ant or whatever) to build and deploy your app to the ubuntu server. Then start the app with remote debugging enabled:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y -jar theApp.jar
```

Then use Eclipse to remote debug the app.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

Comment: Assuming there is no firewall in between this is the answer what you need

Answer (score 1):

Java offers you remote debugging.

Here's a tutorial on this subject:

[How To Debug a Remote Java Application](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat)

Answer (score 0):

you can use VNC/NoMachine clients to get a remote GUI session on your server and develop directly on the server machine itself. We use [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) at work to connect to RedHat boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well you can always use vim+commandline magic to do the development on the server. If you are too used to using Eclipse. Check out [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) project which will give eclipse functionality on your vim which you can run on your server to do the development.

Another method is to use a git repo, all your changes you can push to the server and then compile on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really good (and fast) connection to your linux machine, you can install Eclipse directly there and develop over SSH session. Using X11 tunneling and [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)

- Install Java and Eclipse on your Linux machine
- Install [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) on your Windows client (see installation/setup instructions)
- Place your source files (Eclipse workspace) somewhere at Linux machine
- Run Eclipse directly at Linux over SSH tunneling from Windows machine (see Xming guide)
- Now everything is run at Linux and you have full access to debugging etc.